# The best shape for most surface area to maximize the amount of friction

Tags: friction

I read a funny conversation about 3D printers and their filament (the plastic that gets melted). Filament is round and is fed to an extruder, which is basically just a gear with teeth:

[image]

The idler roller and toothed wheel in the above image is usually flat, which means it hits the least amount of surface on a square (if we assume the filament isn't squished by the spring):

[image]

If both the idler roller and toothed wheel weren't flat, they would hit a much larger surface area:

[image]

This would drastically improve the amount of friction, which means the gear has a smaller chance of slipping, which is quite common.

Someone in that funny conversation suggested that if we made the plastic filament square, the amount of surface area would be greater (50% if pushed from left and right side), if the idler roller and toothed wheel were flat. That's completely true and I agree with that:

[image]

However, I am under the impression that by keeping the filament round, and then changing the shape of the idler roller and toothed wheel to touch more of the surface (instead of being flat), that you would gain more friction.

One problem: I'm not sure how that translates, when it's only being pushed from one axis. I would assume that the center part would produce the most friction, and friction would decrease slowly, the farther up the circle you get:

[image]

What kind of physics do I have to look into? Someone probably has done a paper on this somewhere. I essentially just want to know, if something is being "pushed through" using friction, which shape is best, if we only push from two sides?

Comment: I expect the filament is getting deformed somewhat by the pressure. That's especially what I expect from a toothed drive wheel. Meaning it isn't friction as such pushing the filament through.  The drivers with scoops out would be a challenge to keep the filament aligned correctly.

Comment: To answer this you need to do some FEA work since it involves non-Hertzian contact theory (finite width of the wheel makes it a lot more difficult to deal with).

Find and download [HertzWin](https://www.vinksda.com/toolkit-mechanical-calculations/hertz-contact-stress-calculations/) to get an idea of what the Hertzian contact stress distribution looks like for various scenarios. This problem involves an elliptical contact with double radii on both sides. I recommend a gripping contact where the wheel profile radius < filament radius.